# Joomla not Showing Dropdown SubMenu to SubMenu?

Tags: php, joomla

I created a dropdown menu in my joomla website. I created the menu like this:

```
Parent-1
     sub menu-1
              sub menu-1
              sub menu-2  
     sub menu-2
     sub menu-3
     sub menu-4
parent-2
parent-3
parent-4
```

This is how I created the menu, but joomla shows only the parent of submenu not showing the submenu of submenu.

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Have you enabled the parameter show child in menu module ?

Comment: can you please add a link to your site so it can be looked at?

Comment: yes sir i enabled the parameter show child menu module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with this configuration, in the back-end go to "extensions" -> "Module manager"
-> "the name of the module which linked to the menu"

[image: It should work with this configuration]

Comment: how and where change to configuration please tell me